# Exponential sums/Laplace transform for $L^1\cap L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, exponential-function

This is perhaps completely trivial, but I'm not sure:

Suppose we have a function $f(x)\in L^1\cap L^2, (-\infty,\infty)$ and a trigonometric sum over a countably infinite set of complex numbers which converge (perhaps distributionally) to $f(x)$. Perhaps something like:
$$f(x)=\sum_{s\in S} \eta_se^{|x|\sigma+ix\omega}$$

where $S$ is a countably infinite set of complex numbers $s=\sigma+i\omega$ with $\sigma\ge 0$ and $\eta_s$ are some weights.

QUESTION: must it be the case that $\sigma=0$ for all $s$? The idea is that we have something like a Fourier Transform with a discrete spectrum and the possibility of exponential growth for the basis (which i am curious if we can rule out).

I think this question is related to the Fourier and Laplace transforms. I have a feeling that the answer is yes because Fourier Inversion is valid for functions in $L^1\cap L^2$ (which implies that $\sigma=0$). I don't know if there is more to show, such as if there is a $\sigma_s>0$ then the exponential growth cannot be neutralized by other $\sigma_s$'s.

thank you

Comment: No; take the index set to be over all complex numbers with (say) integer coordinates, and define $\eta_s = 1$ if $s = -1+i$ and $0$ otherwise. Then $f(x) = e^{-x+ix} \in L^1\cap L^2$. Note that you can’t write $f$ as a proper Fourier series, since it’s not periodic.

Comment: @kieransquared thank you for this.... you pointed out an issue with my question.... i think i really meant to ask for $Re(s)\ge 0$. ill adjust the question now.

Comment: Unclear. $\sigma=\sigma_s$ ? $\sum_{s\in S}$ where $S$ is a countably infinite subset of $\Re(s)\ge 0$ ? Did you mean that for all $x\in \Bbb{R}$ the series converges to $f(x)$ ?

Comment: @reuns yes, so similar to a FT with discrete spectrum, but with the possibility of exponential growth in the basis.

Comment: Why don't you edit/clarify your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No because an exponential sum can converge pointwise to $0$ for all $x$.

I interpret your question as given 3 sequences $(\sigma_n),(\omega_n), (\eta_n)$ with $\sigma_n\ge 0$ and the $\sigma_n+i\omega_n$ distinct, if $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \eta_n e^{\sigma_n |x|+i\omega_n x}$$ converges for all $x$, to $f(x)$, such that $f\in L^1 \cap L^2$, should we have that $\forall n,\sigma_n = 0$?

For a counter-example, start with $F_1(y) = 1_{y\in [0,1]}$,
then for each $n$, find the least (for the lexicographical order) integers $k\ge 0,a\in \Bbb{Z},b\le 0$ such that $$\forall y, \qquad F_n(y)\ge \frac1n 1_{y\in [\pi^{-n}+a/2^k,\pi^{-n}+(a+1-b)/2^k]}$$ and set $F_{n+1}(y)=F_n(y)-\frac1n 1_{y\in [\pi^{-n}+a/2^k,\pi^{-n}+(a+1-b)/2^k]}$.
If no such $k,a,b$ exist set $F_{n+1}=F_n$.

It is not hard to see that $F_n$ converges to $0$ in $L^1$, that $\lim_{n\to \infty} F_n'$ is a series of weighted Dirac delta peaks at distinct abscissa, and that the Fourier transform of $F_n'$ is an exponential sum at distinct frequencies and which converges to $0$ pointwise. Multiplying it with $e^{|x|}$ gives a counter-example.